# First migration to a new PostgreSQL database. ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python, django, database, python-3.x, postgresql

Have the models.py that have worked successfully with the SQLite database. Now trying to use PostgreSQL. If you look at the Traceback it seems like there is a string default value for an integer field. I just couldn't see it. Commented most of the fields, made migrations and still the same issue.

Traceback

```
 Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, players, sessions, silk, users
Running migrations:
  Applying players.0007_auto_20190130_1427...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\temp\YandexDisk\programming\py\nhl_web_app\manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py",
 line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py",
 line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", lin
e 316, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", lin
e 353, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", lin
e 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migr
ate.py", line 203, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", l
ine 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=f
ake_initial)
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", l
ine 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)

  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", l
ine 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py",
line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)

  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fiel
ds.py", line 216, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py",
line 523, in alter_field
    old_db_params, new_db_params, strict)
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\schema
.py", line 122, in _alter_field
    new_db_params, strict,
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py",
line 627, in _alter_field
    new_default = self.effective_default(new_field)
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py",
line 239, in effective_default
    return field.get_db_prep_save(default, self.connection)
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py"
, line 790, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py"
, line 785, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py"
, line 1807, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

model.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.text import slugify
from players.storage import OverwriteStorage


class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, default='nme')
    nhl_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True, default=25)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    # image = models.ImageField(upload_to='players_pics', storage=OverwriteStorage(), max_length=None)
    # team = models.CharField(max_length=128, default='')
    # position = models.CharField(max_length=128, default='')
    # height = models.CharField(max_length=128, default='')
    # weight = models.IntegerField(default=25)
    # birth_date = models.CharField(max_length=128, default='')
    # birth_city = models.CharField(max_length=128, default='')
    # birth_state = models.CharField(max_length=128, default='')
    # birth_country = models.CharField(max_length=128, default='')
    # nation = models.CharField(max_length=128, default='')
    # draft_year = models.CharField(max_length=128, default='')
    # draft_number = models.CharField(max_length=128, default='')
    # games = models.IntegerField(default=25)
    # pl_number = models.IntegerField(null=True, default=25)
    # age = models.IntegerField(null=True, default=25)
    # roster_status = models.CharField(max_length=128, default='')
    # captain = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    # alt_captain = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        is_new = self.pk is None
        if is_new:
            self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Player, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Skater(Player):
    # favorite = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='favorite_s', blank=True)
    goals = models.IntegerField(default=10)
    # goals_avg = models.FloatField(default=10)
    # assists = models.IntegerField()
    # assists_avg = models.FloatField(default=10)
    # points = models.IntegerField()
    # points_avg = models.FloatField(default=10)
    # plus_minus = models.IntegerField()
    # plus_minus_avg = models.FloatField(default=10)
    # penalty_min = models.IntegerField()
    # penalty_min_avg = models.FloatField(default=10)
    # shots = models.IntegerField()
    # shots_avg = models.FloatField(default=10)
    # hits = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    # hits_avg = models.FloatField(default=10, null=True)
    # blocks = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    # blocks_avg = models.FloatField(default=10, null=True)
    # faceoff_wins = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    # faceoff_wins_avg = models.FloatField(default=10, null=True)
    # pp_points = models.IntegerField()
    # pp_points_avg = models.FloatField(default=10)
    # sh_points = models.IntegerField()
    # sh_points_avg = models.FloatField(default=10)
    # time_on_ice = models.CharField(max_length=128, default='')
    # time_on_ice_pp = models.CharField(max_length=128, default='')
    # time_on_ice_sh = models.CharField(max_length=128, default='')


class Goalie(Player):
    # favorite = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='favorite_g', blank=True)
    wins = models.IntegerField(default=10)
    # losses = models.IntegerField()
    # ot_losses = models.IntegerField()
    # goals_against_av = models.FloatField()
    # saves_perc = models.FloatField()
    # saves = models.IntegerField()
    # shotouts = models.IntegerField()
```

settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'nhl_web_app_1',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '***',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide content of `0007_auto_20190130_1427.py` migration file

Comment: @awesoon, You got that right. I just couldn't read the traceback properly. Didn't think it would try to apply an old migrations file. Deleted all of the migrations and now couldn't apply the new, initial migration. It's saying 'No migrations to apply'

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/m9WMAzsu5_Vo6g - screen

Comment: Did you rollback DB as well? If this is local DB without any production data you can either rollback by specifying the latest migration you want to be applied (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-migrate), rollback manually with raw DDL or just drop and recreate DB.

Comment: Tried some of these and just ended up with creating a new Postgre database. It works as expected. Thanks!

Comment: Please write an answer with details and accept it, just not to leave the question unanswered. According to your screenshot, the issue was in the migration file (`default=''`). This is probably sqlite specific, not sure.

Comment: ok, I''m just not sure why the 'migrate' command was trying to apply an old migration file.

Comment: `migrate` does not know about old or new migrations, it only knows which of them are applied or not and by default it tries to apply all unapplied migrations. All applied migrations are stored in the `django_migrations` table.

Comment: The *whole point* of migrations is that Django will apply them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of @awesoon, I was able to locate the error.

The problem was in the migration file `0007_auto_20190130_1427.py`

I've a had a string default value for an `IntegerField` - `default=''`

```
migrations.AlterField(
    model_name='skater',
    name='time_on_ice_pp',
    field=models.IntegerField(default='', null=True),
),
```

Needed to replace this default value with any integer.

```
migrations.AlterField(
    model_name='skater',
    name='time_on_ice_pp',
    field=models.IntegerField(default=10, null=True),
),
```